# R If a data.frame variable contains a vector, how to operate/filter on the vector?

Tags: r, vector, tidyverse, rowwise

Original Sample code:

```
v1 = c('Tom','Dick','Harry')
d1 <- data.frame(v1)

l1 <- c('20200101','20200202','20200303')
l2 <- c('20200101','20200202')
l3 <- c('20200101','20200202','20200303','20200404')
v2 = c(l1,l2,l3)
d1$v2 = v2
d2 <- d1

d2$len_v2 = c(3,2,4)
```

Revised Sample code that solves Q1 problem. Issue was that I did not pass in a list of lists.

`v2 = c(l1,l2,l3)` flattens the list of lists and causes an error:

```
library(tidyverse)
v1 <- c('Tom','Dick','Harry')
d1 <- data.frame(v1)

l1 <- c('20200101','20200202','20200303')
l2 <- c('20200101','20200202')
l3 <- c('20200101','20200202','20200303','20200404')
v2 <- list(l1,l2,l3)
d1$v2 <- v2
d2 <- d1 %>% mutate(len_v2 = lengths(v2))
```

I typically use tidyverse.

Q1 >> How to calculate 'len_v2' as a variable in D1?   Is there a rowwise operation to do this?

A1 >> SOLVED.

Q2 >> Are there ways to apply operations to the lists in the v2 variable, such as filtering, either resulting in a new list variable, or dropping rows that did not pass a condition on the v2 list variable?

For example, if I wanted to return all rows which had 20200303 in them to get a resulting d3 with the first and third rows only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `list` column, then we can use `lengths`

```
library(dplyr)
d2 %>%
   mutate(len_v2 = lengths(v2))
```

-output

```
#    v1                                     v2 len_v2
#1   Tom           20200101, 20200202, 20200303      3
#2  Dick                     20200101, 20200202      2
#3 Harry 20200101, 20200202, 20200303, 20200404      4
```

For `filter`ing, can use `map` to loop over the `list`, apply the logical expression and return a logical vector to `filter` the rows

```
library(purrr)
d2 %>%
    filter(map_lgl(v2, ~ '20200303' %in% .x))

#     v1                                     v2 len_v2
#1   Tom           20200101, 20200202, 20200303      3
#2 Harry 20200101, 20200202, 20200303, 20200404      4
```

assuming that

```
v2 <- list(l1,l2,l3)
```

in the OP's code